# Haskell - Pattern Matching form (x:y:zs)

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching

I am having difficulty understanding how to use pattern matching in guards.

I have this sample function, whose purpose is to return the last character in a string.

```
myFun :: [Char] -> Char
myFun str@(f:s:rst)
      | str == ""  = error "0 length string"
      | length str == 1 = head str
      | rst == "" = s
      | otherwise = lame (s:rst)
```

It is failing with "Non-exhaustive patterns in function" when passed a string with a single character.

I assume that Haskell realizes it can't use the form `(f:s:rst)` to match a single element list, and then fails prior to trying to evaluate the call to `length`.

How do I make a guard that will tell Haskell what to do when there is only a single element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are pattern matching at the function definition level. The way you have described it, you are only covering the case where the string is at least two characters long:

```
myFun str@(f:s:rst)
```

You need to handle other cases as well. You can have a catch-all handler like this (needs to go as the last pattern):

```
myFun _ = ...
```

Or if you want to handle, for instance, the empty string, like this (prior to the catch-all):

```
myFun [] = ...
```

As to the purpose of your function, you are probably better off just using pattern matching and not using guards.

```
myFun :: [Char] -> Char
myFun [] = error "empty string"
myFun [x] = x
myFun (x:xs) = myFun xs
```

(Note that it would be more idiomatic to return a `Maybe Char` instead of crashing your program)

Comment: That works -
Realistically there are a variety of easier / better ways to do this.

What I'm really struggling with here is trying to figure out if there is a way to tell guards what to do if an argument can't be deconstructed via the provided pattern.

Should I take your response to mean that : 
"Yes, if you define the pattern in the function declaration, that is not possible when using guards"

Comment: The function-level pattern matching happens first, which means that the first two guard conditions you have can never possibly be met (those where you check for `str` of zero or one length)

Answer (score 1):

Based on the particularly helpful answer from Chad Gilbert, and some additional tinkering,
I have found a way to have my cake and eat it to.
In case anyone has a similar stumbling block, here is a way to specify uncovered cases prior to declaring your guards:

```
myFun :: [Char] -> Char
myFun "" = ""
myFun str@(s:rst)
      | rst == "" = s
      | otherwise = myFun (s:rst)
```

This also works with multiple args :

```
strSplit :: [Char] -> [[Char]] -> [[Char]]
strSplit str [] = strSplit str [""]
strSplit "" _ = [""]
strSplit str@(s1:ns) list@(x:xs)
       | s1 == '|' = strSplit ns ("":list)
       | ns == "" = map reverse $ ((s1 : x) : xs)
       | otherwise  = strSplit ns ((s1 : x) : xs)
```

Or with stuff using the original `pattern@(first:second:rest)` idea:

```
    lastTwo :: [Char]->[Char]
    lastTwo "" = ""
    lastTwo [x] = [x]
    lastTwo str@(f:s:rst)
            | rst =="" = [f,s]
            | otherwise = lastTwo (s:rst)
```

This is probably super obvious to folks more familiar with Haskell, but I didn't realize that you were "allowed" to just declare the function multiple times using different syntax to cover different cases.

Comment: Just for fun, you might also like: `lastTwo = reverse . take 2 . reverse`.